# replace multiple smart layers at every export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting

Can anyone suggest me a Photoshop extension: That can replace multiple smart layers at every export and can auto-fit the new image to the original dimension of the replaced smart layer so there is no need to resize the source images.

I'm having a script that only:

1. get files
2. replace contents

But cannot "save" it, I require a script for saving the file to  separate folder. The old extension:

```
// Replace SmartObject’s Content and Save as PSD
// 2017, use it at your own risk
#target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;
    var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
    // PSD Options;
    psdOpts = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
    psdOpts.embedColorProfile = true;
    psdOpts.alphaChannels = true;
    psdOpts.layers = true;
    psdOpts.spotColors = true;
    // Check if layer is SmartObject;
    if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {
        alert("selected layer is not a smart object")
    } else {
        // Select Files;
        if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", "*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg", true)
        } else {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", getFiles, true)
        };
        if (theFiles) {
            for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
                // Replace SmartObject
                theLayer = replaceContents(theFiles[m], theLayer);
                var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
                // Save JPG
                myDocument.saveAs((new File(thePath + "/" + theName + "_" + theNewName + ".psd")), psdOpts, true);
            }
        }
    }
};
// Get PSDs, TIFs and JPGs from files
function getFiles(theFile) {
    if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|tif|jpg)$/i) != null || theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
        return true
    };
};
// Replace SmartObject Contents
function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
    // =======================================================
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site. You don't need to post a new almost similar question. You're just supposed to edit the original one.

Comment: also dont include your email in the question. If your question can not be handled in a srict q and a form then post it elsewhere.

Comment: Hi! you better try elaborating your situation more. like some pictures or GIFs will help us more than the words can.

Comment: @Mr.Online sure